# xymatrix spacing in lyx

Tags: tables, lyx, line-spacing

I'm trying to use lyx to make an `xymatrix` with narrowed spacing between the rows. I found in Peter Gumm's notes http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~gumm/LyX/xypic/xypic.pdf that I could add to the preamble the following code.

```
 \newcommand{\xyR}[1]{%
   \xydef@\xymatrixrowsep@{#1}
 } % end of \xyR
```

and then use `\xyR{}` preceding the matrix entries.

For me, though, in the instant preview I get several mysterious braces preceding the matrix. And when I compile to pdf, I recieve errors "Missing number, treated as zero" and "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."

Alternatively, when I use `\xyR` (without the braces) preceding the matrix entires, in the instant preview I see the entire matrix in a single row, and when I compile to pdf I recieve "Misplaced alignment tab character &."

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyR}[1]{%
\xydef@\xymatrixrowsep@{#1}
} % end of \xyR
\makeatother


\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}




$\xyR\xymatrix{A & B\\
C & D\\
E & F
}
$
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try adding `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after those three lines.

Comment: @egreg Doesn't change.

Comment: We need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (or not working as well).

Comment: @egreg I edited the question with the example. (Is that what you meant?) I suppose, it is a not working one.

Answer (score 1):

The `\xyR` macro requires an argument, the desired spacing between rows.

Here's how you should use it, with also a simpler approach: if you follow `\xymatrix` with `@R=<dimen>`, the given length will be used as the space between rows; you can also use

```
\xymatrix@R+<dimen>
\xymatrix@R-<dimen>
```

that respectively add or subtract the given length from the default one. No need for `\xyR`, as you see.

I removed the LyX things, to make the answer more general.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyR}[1]{%
\xydef@\xymatrixrowsep@{#1}
} % end of \xyR
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Normal $\xymatrix{A & B\\
C & D\\
E & F
}
$

Modified $\xyR{0pt}\xymatrix{A & B\\
C & D\\
E & F
}
$

Simpler $\xymatrix@R=0pt{A & B\\
C & D\\
E & F
}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated! Somehow, the first solution is still giving me problems. It displays correctly in the instant preview but does not compile "Missing $ inserted." The second solution, which, little I know, I thought would not work in lyx because of the @, turned out to work for me. Thanks.